# How to override forgot password validation in Laravel Fortify?

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-fortify

I'm using Laravel Fortify for user authentication in my Laravel application. I have overridden the validation for the login process by using the Fortify::authenticateUsing method, which allows me to add custom validation rules. However, I'm facing difficulty in finding a similar method or approach for customizing the validation rules for the forgot password functionality.

Specifically, I want to override the validation rules for the email field and add google recaptcha validation in the forgot password form. I have tried searching through the Laravel Fortify documentation, but I couldn't find a direct solution. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?

Here is an example of what I've tried for the login process:

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
    // Custom authentication logic and validation rules go here
});
```

This method allows me to add custom validation rules and perform additional checks during the login process. However, I'm unable to find a similar approach for the forgot password functionality.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Fortify route file is inside vendor/laravel/fortify/routes folder. You can transfer and edit the routes here on your own route file.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to disable fortify routes by opening the FortifyServiceProvider file and include the code `Fortify::ignoreRoutes();` in the register method:

```
public function register(): void
{
    Fortify::ignoreRoutes();
}
```

After that move the Fortify routes from the vendor\laravel\fortify\routes\routes.php file to your web routes file in web.php.

Now, update the password.email route in your web routes file. Don't forget to import the necessary classes:

```
Route::post('/forgot-password', function (Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    ], [
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'Please complete the reCAPTCHA verification.',
    ]);

    $status = Password::sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

    return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
        ? app(SuccessfulPasswordResetLinkRequestResponse::class, ['status' => $status])
        : app(FailedPasswordResetLinkRequestResponse::class, ['status' => $status]);
})->middleware(['guest'])->name('password.email');
```